# How to create console.log snippet in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I do not know how to do it
I want to write first of all code, then press TAB and this code will be wrapped in brackets with console.log command.
Help please)

Comment: What have you tried? [The documentation](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) is quite simple.

Comment: i did it
but when i am saving snippet and reload sublime it disappear from file

Comment: Please make sure you are saving it with the extension ".sublime-snippet". Maybe you must have missed that.

Comment: saved 
than what should i do?

Answer (score 20):

Here is my approach - Sublime Text 3 (3126) @ Ubuntu 16.04.

Open Sublime Text editor and go to:

`Tools -> Developer -> New Snippet...`

Then paste the following code:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log(${1:}$SELECTION);${0}]]></content>    
    <tabTrigger>console.log</tabTrigger>    
    <scope>text.plain, source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

(`<scope></scope>` is optional, and feel free to put whatever you want in `<tabTrigger></tabTrigger>` section)

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, choose name (e.g. `console.log.sublime-snippet`) and save it.

Open any JS file, start typing `console` and the snippet will appear.

Answer (score 11):

*Update: Following my snippet answer below, is another hack that does not require a snippet (useful when you are using other editors).*

Put this file in `/packages/User/<optional subFolder Name>/console_log.sublime-snippet`

If you goto `Tools -> Developer -> New Snippet..`
then `crtl-S` (when you're done typing), it'll automatically open the correct folder up for you.

**console_log.sublime-snippet**:

```
   <snippet>
        <content><![CDATA[console.log($1);$0]]></content>
        <tabTrigger>conl</tabTrigger>
        <scope>text.html,source.js</scope>
        <description>console.log()</description>
    </snippet>
```

Type: `conl` <kbd>tab</kbd> and: `console.log();` appears in your editor.

Cursor will automatically be placed between the `()`to allow quick typing of your log message.
When finished, click <kbd>tab</kbd> again, and the cursor will be moved past the `;`.

- Tab behaviour is controlled by the `$1`  and `$0` in the snippet.
- The `conl` between `tabTrigger` tags defines the keystrokes (not including `tab`) that will trigger the snippet to run.  Change it to whatever shortcut makes sense to you.
- `description` tags (optional) define what "hint" you want sublime to show when listing tab-completion "match" options.
- `scope` tags (optional) limit the snippet to trigger only when working in files of the listed types

**Here is an advanced version of this snippet I use for debug logging.**
It encourages labeling the variable that I want to look at.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log('$2:', $1);$0]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cl</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html,source.js</scope>
    <description>console.log()</description>
</snippet>
```

This one is triggered by `cl`, and the

- 1st <kbd>tab</kbd> takes me (past the comma) to the location where I am to type in the **variable name**,
- 2nd <kbd>tab</kbd> takes me (between the quotes) to the location where I am to type in the **label**
- 3rd <kbd>tab</kbd> takes me (past the semi-colon) to continue coding

I find that my mind is most interested in typing in the variable I'm interested in looking at, then almost as an afterthought, it is interested in labeling it.
Plus, I often want to pre-pend label with the name of the calling function, so it's cognitively easier to get the variable out of the way, then add labeling details. Hence the <kbd>tab</kbd> order.

If that order seems unnatural, just swap the `$1` and `$2` like so:

```
<content><![CDATA[console.log('$1:', $2);$0]]></content>
```

This will put the cursor:

- 1st <kbd>tab</kbd> between the quotes first (to type in your **label** for the variable),
- 2nd <kbd>tab</kbd> after the comma second (to enter the **variable** you want to look at), and
- 3rd <kbd>tab</kbd> after the semi-colon last (to continue coding).

*EDIT:*

- *For use with JSX files ending in .js, add `source.jsx` to the `source` tag.*
- *Change the trigger to `lg` so as to interfere with `class` or `className` from emmet or sublime code completion.*

---

The other hack I use for console.log if I am inside any other editor that has multi-cursor functionality is to:

- type: `console.log('',` 
  (include *both* quotation marks, and a final space.)
  Most editors will also add the closing paren: `console.log('',)`
- then I `Ctrl-Click` between the `''` quotation marks.
  This puts a second cursor between the quotes.
- type the variable name (say `varName`)
- Now the line looks like: `console.log('varName', varName)`
- (if adding more variables, click before the closing `)`,
  add `, '',` 
  and again `ctrl-click` between the quotes.)
- Click the `End` key to add the final `;`

Alternatively I initially initially type `console.log;`
then arrow-left to add `('',` , then do the control-click trick.
This way I do not forget to add the final `;` when I am done.

Another way, is to not add quotation marks in the above steps:

- Instead, just hit `,` , and immediately
- `Ctrl-click` in front of the comma to give yourself 2 cursors inside the parenthesis: `console.log(, )`.
- Type in the variable.
- double-click the first copy of the variable
- click on a quotation mark `'`.
  In Sublime, and many other editors, the highlighted word will then be *wrapped* in that quotation mark: `console.log('varName', varName)`
  (In contrast, traditional editors would replace the highlighted word with the quotation mark).
- add `;` to the end of the line

Comment: this is a great way, thank you

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Go to tools -> New snippet.

Step 2: Insert below code(Just a sample one with basic tags. For more info please refer [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html))

```
 <snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[Hello, this is sample snippet ]]></content>
  <tabTrigger>hello</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Step 3: Save the file. Extension must be 'sublime-snippet' for example: hello.sublime-snippet

Step 4: Thats all. You can now open any other file in sublime and type `hello` and hit `TAB` key. which will bring the text in place of hello `Hello, this is sample snippet`

Answer (score 3):

> Go to Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Key Bindings - User and add this
>   JSON to the file and save it:

```
[
    { "keys": ["tab"],
      "command": "insert_snippet",
      "args": {
        "contents": "console.log(${1:}$SELECTION);${0}"
      }
    }
]
```

Now select any code and just press tab key

Comment: it is adding the console.log in place of the text. How can i find the next available line to put it.

Comment: add another command on same key and try something like this "args": {"by": "lines", "forward": true},

Comment: try this its working just add \n 
{ 
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "${1:$SELECTION}\nconsole.log(${1:$SELECTION});\n"
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
    ]
},
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "insert_snippet",
    "args": {
        "contents": "\nconsole.log(${1:$SELECTION});\n"
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late, but can't stop myself from suggesting some improvement.

To me actually this makes more sense and is more helpful too.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[console.log('${1:Variable/Resource}:',${1:Variable/Resource});$0]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>cons.log</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html,source.js</scope>
    <description>console.log(Label:Variable/Resource)</description>
</snippet>
```

This way you can actually see what variable you're seeing data/content of, when you're forced to print multiple variables/resources during debugging of a long. complex and tiring script.

Save this as `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text\Packages\User\cons.log.sublime-snippet` or `/packages/User/<optional subFolder Name>/cons.log.sublime-snippet`(if you're in non-Windows OS).